# xunit test failing - something to do with log4net?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, xunit

I have 2 .NET Core test projects, one for integration the other for unit tests.  Both use xUnit.

The unit test passes fine but when I run the integration test - which is by necessity more complex - I get this:

```
------ Run test started ------
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.1418141]   Starting:    Blah.Tax.Service.Integration.Test
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.4896056]     Blah.Tax.Service.Integration.Test.DataServiceTests.Can_Create_Client [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.4916354]       System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'log4net.Core.LoggerManager' threw an exception.
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.4918048]       ---- System.MethodAccessException : Attempt by method 'log4net.Core.LoggerManager.RegisterAppDomainEvents()' to access method 'System.AppDomain.add_ProcessExit(System.EventHandler)' failed.
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.4932551]       Stack Trace:
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.4951484]            at log4net.Core.LoggerManager.GetLogger(Assembly repositoryAssembly, Type type)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.4953039]         ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.4953848]            at log4net.Core.LoggerManager.RegisterAppDomainEvents()
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.4954587]            at log4net.Core.LoggerManager..cctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.5424882]   Finished:    Blah.Tax.Service.Integration.Test
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:02.8672427) ==========
```

The integration test is failing when attempting to connect to DynamoDB.

I don't have any references to `log4net` so I guess it's coming from another package.

I did find this article (https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/632) which sounds similar but I'm stumped otherwise.

Can anyone suggest how I can trace down the problem?

It seems like every release of Visual Studio breaks something with unit tests.

Comment: Looks related to https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/620. Maybe try setting the aws logging settings to system.diagnostics instead of log4net - see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/logging-with-the-aws-sdk-for-net/